# Functional way in IO related tasks

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Most beginners program IO related tasks in an imperative way. Are there any general suggestions to help beginners switching to more functional way in implementing IO related tasks?

As a concrete example consider the task of directory traversing and file processing along the way. For me the imperative way is to walk the directory tree and process each file as in C style languages. I then discovered the [Conduit](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/snoyberg/library-documentation/conduit-overview) library which for me represents the functional way: Build up the source list then consume the list.

So may I say that the "conduit way" is the preferred functional way of programming in IO related tasks?

Comment: Just found a tutorial on the haskell wiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Haskell_IO_for_Imperative_Programmers   But any other suggestions besides this tutorial are welcome

Comment: The conduit way is a special case of interpreting a free monad into IO, which might be a better tool to investigate.

Comment: @JAbrahamson, is there a "'interpret free monad into IO" tool appropriate for a beginner to investigate?  I have been reading a few scattered docs about free monad this week, coincidentally. Is the general idea that we build an IO computation without actually sequencing any actions through the actual operating system (constructing a large chain of nested monad constructors calls), and then evaluate that "whole program" object using something more clever (with exception handlers/resource finalizers or whatever) than tradition Haskell `IO` function implementations (openFile etc)?

Answer (score 2):

The conduit approach isn't to build up the entire list at once and consume it; the point of conduit (and pipes, the other current popular solution to this problem) is that you only consume one element at a time. It's similar to lazy IO, except in a more principled way, because lazy IO is really annoying to reason about and get correct.

The first step is to try to pull as much of your logic as you can into pure functions; instead of writing a `parseFile :: FileName -> Result`, write a `parseContents :: String -> Result` and use readFile (well, you should also probably use Text or ByteString instead of String, but that's not relevant).

For your specific case, you have three concerns: enumerating the files you want to read, reading them, and then processing the contents. So one thing that you could do if you wanted to use `conduit` would be to write a `Source IO FilePath` that produces file names, a `Conduit FilePath IO Text` that takes file names and outputs their contents, and a `Sink Text Result` that takes contents and does whatever with them. You then hook them all up together using `(source $= conduit) $$ sink` or something like that, and you get an `IO Result`.

I believe this is related to reactive programming, btu I don't know too much about reactive programming so I can't say much there.

Comment: And by the way, the [traverse function](http://haddocks.fpcomplete.com/fp/7.4.2/20130829-168/filesystem-conduit/Data-Conduit-Filesystem.html#v:traverse) provides a `Source IO FilePath`.

Answer (score 1):

Obvious answer: for IO tasks you should use IO monad. But I personally don't see big difference between IO monad and imperative code. This is because IO monad wraps mutable state(Operating System) and passes it from one statement to another. Although IO monad doesn't bring mutable variables to your code it allows you to change some mutable state implicitly.

Recently I met interesting approach to handle Input called **reactive programming**. I played with [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki) using Scala bindings and fount it promising. Main idea is to write pure event handlers to different types of events. But killer feature is that event sources can be combined in different ways to make new event source which encapsulate some logic. You can read interesting article called [Your Mouse is a Database](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2169076) to find more about motivation for this approach. I don't sure it will help you to explore filesystem but certainly will help to write interactive programs.